# Can EE handle Millions of Users?

Tags: performance

I’m new to the expression engine project at our business. We are being acquired by a large company and they’re worried that expression engine cannot handle traffic for a exp_members table of 10M, and concurrent connections at about 10k.

I know that most people will naturally ask “It all depends on server resources, and how big is your database…”, and we can always have bigger boxes, I’m not really interested in theoretical limits, my question is a bit more practical than that.

Has anyone had experience with using EE for 5+ millions of users and approx 10k concurrent users, and what has been your experience been with it?

Please help me understand your experience.

It’s a classic “Executive Decision makers (and what they think they understand from a sales slick”
versus Coders and EE fans.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[There's an old post (from 2012) here](http://www.hopstudios.com/blog/the_largest_expressionengine_sites/#.VG-Vc1dgweM) which might go some way to answer the question. You'll note that there are some major sites there.

Ultimately, as you've acknowledged, the matter is one of resources and network infrastructure and not one of software. No system will cope with 10K concurrent connections unless the network is built in such a way as to allow it.

Comment: It's a dated article, but is the best resource I've ever found "The largest confirmed traffic we know of is BroBible at 30,000,000 pages per month." - says it all really. Another interesting article: http://bluefishds.com/blog/article/is-expressionengine-an-enterprise-content-management-system

Answer (score 0):

I was working a site with ~60K users and 2-3K being active every day running on EE1 (that's been really a while ago). But we were really pushing EE to it's limits there. Can't say anything about EE2.